# How to solve "Error converting data type varchar to date "

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure like this. If I try to execute it for 1st of june to 31st of july, it shows a conversion error. Can anyone please help how to fix this? It shows the results for 1st of june and 30th of july working fine. But if I use 31st july it's not working.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[Samp]
      (@StartDate date ,
       @EndDate date,
       @Flowid int)
AS
BEGIN
    if(@Flowid = 909)
    begin
        select 
            COUNT(distinct a.Audit_id)  
        from  
            [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[CustomValues909] a 
        join 
            [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[Audit] b on a.id = b.id
        join 
            [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[Substatus] c on c.Id = b.Substatus_id
        where 
            c.MajorStatus <> 'Cancelled' 
            and a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date >= @StartDate
            and a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date <= @EndDate
     end
     else if @Flowid = 1010
     begin 
         select 
             COUNT(distinct a.Audit_id)  
         from  
             [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[CustomValues1010] a 
         join 
             [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[Audit] b on a.id = b.id
         join 
             [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[Substatus] c on c.Id = b.Substatus_id
         where 
             c.MajorStatus <> 'Cancelled' 
             and a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date >= @StartDate
             and a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date <= @EndDate
    end
    else if @Flowid = 101
    begin
        select 
            COUNT(distinct a.Audit_id)  
        from  
            [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[CustomValues101] a 
        join 
            [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[Audit] b on a.id = b.id
        join 
            [Prod_Workflow_Client41].[dbo].[Substatus] c on c.Id = b.Substatus_id
        where 
            c.MajorStatus <> 'Cancelled' 
            and a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date >= @StartDate
            and a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date <= @EndDate
   end
end
--exec [dbo].[Samp] '01/06/2015','31/06/2015',909
--exec [dbo].[Samp] '01/06/2015','30/06/2015',1010
--exec [dbo].[Samp] '01/06/2015','30/06/2015',101
```

Comment: You should try to break down your code to the part which causes to problem

Comment: a.Auditor_Reviewed_Date column is nvarchar(max) datatype..

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have a **DATE** - you should **store it as such!** Don't store dates as `varchar` and most definitely not as `varchar(max)` (or have you ever seen a date that's nearly **2 billion characters** long ?!?!)

Comment: send me the correct query..Bcz im not well in conversion..I am new to the sql

Comment: does is it work like that: --exec [dbo].[Samp] '20150601','20150630',909 or 20150731?

Answer (score 1):

SQL server uses the US date format (mm/dd/yyyy) for these implicit conversions, so entering `'01/06/2015'` is actually converted to the **6th of January 2015**, which is obviously a valid date.  If you enter `'31/07/2015'` SQL server will attempt to convert that to the **7th day of the 31st month**, which is invalid and why you get the conversion error.

Also, in your example, you've specified the 31st of June 2015, which isn't a date.

Comment: Firstly you need to make sure you put the dates in the right format when typing them mm/dd/yyyy do 31st of July would be 07/31/2015, secondly, you need to make sure you always enter a valid date, your example in your question showed you trying to enter the 31st of June, which is not a date.

Comment: in what format i need to give while execute..i want to give like 01/06/2015 to 30/06/2015 it gives the wrong results